# What happens to amperage (current) in a step-down transformer?

Tags: transformer, three-phase, amperage

I have 480 V, 3-phase, 800 A coming in. If I use a step-down transformer to bring it to 240 V, 3-phase, do I then have 1600 A available?

Comment: Watts is watts.

Comment: Generally, yes. You will have some losses in the transformer - a few percent.

Comment: @transistor:  "a few percent" is  about 12kW lost in the transfer of 384kW.  Can you post a budget justifying your position?

Comment: This sounds like a copied & pasted homework problem with no indication that you've actually thought about it at all.

Comment: @iAdjunct If it is homework, the teacher who imagined this question doesn't have very high expectations for his students... I actually prefer to think it's not homework and that th OP just doesn't have any electrical engineering background... But, wait... in this case, why is he messing around with 1600 amps ? Oh, well...

Comment: You are not taking into consideration its 3 phase and the square root. Its not just IxE= KVA.

Comment: Phase to phase, line to line, dust to dust

Answer (score 2):

Yes, minus the losses, and provided that your transformer is rated for this power.

Don't know what to say more.

Comment: Sometimes silence is a virtue.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, 300kVA transformers have an efficiency of ~98.6%, though this value will vary depending on how the transformer is constructed, housed, cooled, etc. Assuming this figure is accurate, it would suggest that your output power would be approximately 384kVA * 0.986 = 378.624kVA. Divide this by your voltage (240V) and you get about 1577.6A available. There will also be losses in your cabling and surely your load, but you can expect to have this current available directly from the transformer, assuming a perfect load (no losses).

Comment: what would cause the amps to go up instead?

Comment: Conservation of energy. When the voltage is stepped down, the energy doesn't just disappear. It "transforms" into higher amperage similar to a gear ratio change where you're trading speed for torque and vise versa.

Comment: For (apparent) power, see [David Guerra's comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/237091/what-happens-to-amperage-current-in-a-step-down-transformer/661116#comment1758556_237091).

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, yes, but be mindful of the losses. I just wanted to add that you can use some crude calculation with voltage and current to understand this:

P = V · I

Now it should be clear that as long as the ratio between current and voltage remains the same, the power will stay the same. Just remember to account for transformer losses.